# Under Review status vs Decision Pending (Taylor & Francis journal)

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, journal-workflow

In the ScholarOne system (one of Taylor & Francis journals), the manuscript status is "Under Review". However, under the regular submission system, the status is "Decision Pending". Which of the two instances is correct?

Comment: How would it help you to know? It's pointless to obsess over submitted papers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper I published recently was submitted through ScholarOne system, and based on my experience, after the review before editor's decision, the status remains under review. Recently, I learnt that the submission can also be done through the Taylor & Francis website, and there when the paper returns from review it shows decision pending (waiting for editorial decision), while in the Scholar One system it shows under review. I am experiencing the same thing. But what I understand is that the experts review is completed awaiting editor's decision. So the manuscript status "decision pending" and "under review" can be the same.